# Create a fix button with scrollbar in Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, scrollbar

I run an example about scrollbar based [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter). But I want to add a button (**Prev**) to frame and when scrollbar moves down, this button still stay there, while other content moves along with scrollbar.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        self.populate()

    def populate(self):

        button = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Prev')
        button.grid(row=0, columns=1)

        for row in range(1,100):
            tk.Label(self.frame, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1", relief="solid").grid(row=row, column=0)
            t="this is the second column for row %s" %row
            tk.Label(self.frame, text=t).grid(row=row, column=1)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: you should use `grid()` here and just place the button on top of the area that is being scrolled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `pack()` as well but I prefer to use `grid()`

What you need to do is place the button in root on row 0 and place the class frame on row 1 of root. This should fix your problem.

When using `grid()` we need to manage the weights of the rows and columns so you get the growing and shrinking behavior when we resize the window. We can do this with `rowconfigute()` and `columnconfigute()`. For this program we need to configure the weights of root.

To get the button to stay at the left we can use `sticky = "w"` inside of `grid()` to chose the side to stick to.

Take a look at the below code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = "nsew")
        self.canvas.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        self.populate()

    def populate(self):

        button = tk.Button(root, text='Prev')
        button.grid(row=0, columns=1, sticky = "w")

        for row in range(1,100):
            tk.Label(self.frame, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1", relief="solid").grid(row=row, column=0)
            t="this is the second column for row %s" %row
            tk.Label(self.frame, text=t).grid(row=row, column=1)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    root.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
    Example(root).grid(row = 1)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you so much. And now, I want to put the button in the center. How can I do it?